# CSS selector giving strange results

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'm getting some strange results from one of my selectors.

After a reset, I have some base settings - this being one:

```
a:not([class]) {
    text-decoration:underline;

    &:link, &:visited, &:hover, &:active {
        color:@primaryColor;
    }
    &:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
}
```

It does the job - partly.

This anchor with no href works

```
<a class="link-more mt24">Learn more</a>
```

However this anchor with an href doesn't work.

```
<a class="link-more mt24" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk">Learn more</a>
```

By work I mean that the first link correctly gets ignored, the second link isn't ignored even though it has a class.

For completeness, this is what Less is pushing out:

```
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:not([class]):link,
a:not([class]):visited,
a:not([class]):hover,
a:not([class]):active {
  color: #03a9f4;
}
a:not([class]):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be helpful if you also provided the outputted / processed CSS too...

Comment: Just done it David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is as expected. `a:not([class])` would select and style `a` elements that don't have the `class` attribute. So the third `a` in the below snippet is underlined as it doesn't have `class` attribute.

The first `a` doesn't get the underline because `a` elements without `href` attribute assigned to it won't get the underline by default. This is because the `text-decoration: underline` is normally set using a selector like `a:-webkit-any-link` (WebKit specific, but other UA's will have similar ones).

The second `a` has the underline because of the default styling (indicated above) that is applied by the UA for `a` tags. The `a:not([class])` does not have any effect on it (that is, it is not the reason for the underline) because the selector won't even point to that element.

If you want all the `a` elements with `class` to not have underline then use `a[class]` and remove the underline.

```css
a[class] { /* if you remove this selector, the second link will be underlined */
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:not([class]):link,
a:not([class]):visited,
a:not([class]):hover,
a:not([class]):active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
a:not([class]):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="link-more mt24">Learn more</a>
<a class="link-more mt24" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk">Learn more</a>
<a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk">Learn more</a>
```

Comment: Thats odd, it's not the result I'm getting. As soon as I add the 'href', the selector fails - in my instance link 2 is underlined too.

Comment: When you add the `href` it will get underlined by default because of the UA style. Refer to the update I just made to the answer. In my snippet the second one doesn't get the underline because I have set `a[class] { text-decoration: none}` which targets all `a` elements with class attribute and removes the underline.

Comment: Gotcha Harry - tried and works. Its the end of the day, and I think it would have taken me quite a while to come to the realisation. Thanks.